# Jquery - load element by id and prepend to div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble doing my project. Basically, I have many dialog `div`s in another HTML and have to load the one needed and prepend it to my wrapper `div`.

**How do you load an element by id and prepend to a div?** I've searched for my answer and I came up with using `$.ajax()` but it can't load a single element(or I may be doing something wrong).

JS:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "dialogs.html#modal_" + theRestOfItsId,
   async: false
   }).done(function(html) {
       $("#dialog-area").prepend(html);
});
```

Where the `#dialog-area` is the dialog wrapper(the one that contains all needed dialogs so I can clean it easily)

Although I'm pretty sure it won't work, but that's what I want to do instead of using `$("#dialog-area").load("dialogs.html#modal_" + theRestOfItsId)`.

Comment: what u tried so far ?

Comment: `#dialog-area` using same id all over ?

Comment: why do you use url: "dialogs.html#modal_"? hash and after hash doesn't pass on server. Maybe here is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the [implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e63625e16e0e337d2ddafd6b46313434dfae3f84/src/ajax.js#L133) of `.load()` and make it work like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dialogs.html",
    dataType: 'html',
}).done(function(html) {
   var selector = '#modal_' + theRestOfItsId;

   $('<div>')
     .append($.parseHTML(html))
     .find(selector)
     .prependTo('#dialog-area');
});
```

Comment: i'm testing yours right now. though i have my own answer, it relies on a buffer in the html which is not ideal and the speed would be slower than yours if yours is in fact working

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the code as below. html.d

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "dialogs.html #modal_" + theRestOfItsId,
   async: false
   }).done(function(html) {
       $("#dialog-area").prepend(html.d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own answer while waiting.

### Fix:

```
$("body").append("<div id="temp"></div>");
$("#temp").load('dialogs.html #modal_'+theRestOfItsId, "" , function(){
    var temp = $("#temp").html();
    $(temp).prependTo("#dialog-area");
    $("#temp").remove();
});
```

Comment: This isn't reusable; after the first load it will remove the temporary element and the next call will not do anything.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, oops, i meant to append `temp` before that